# C# namespace structure forcing me to use alias

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'm playing around with namespaces and faced a problem I can't really understand.

My namespace structure in a given class library is as follows:

```
Namespace History
Namespace History.Antiquity
Namespace History.Antiquity.East
Namespace History.Antiquity.West
```

When inside the source file that declares the namespace History, I can't use any of the types defined under `History.Antiquity.East` or `History.Antiquity.West` without fully qualifying them, or without qualifying them starting with "Antiquity".

**Example Code:**

The following for instance, gives me a compile-time error (assuming the type "Persia" is defined in History.Antiquity.East):

```
using History.Antiquity;

namespace History
{
    public class foo
    {
        public foo()
        {
            East.Persia.Conquer(); // error!
        }
    }

}
```

I need to either fully qualify Persia, or qualify it starting from Antiquity. Alternatively, I can introduce an alias:

```
using East = History.Antiquity.East;
```

**Actual question:**

What I can't seem to understand is why is there a problem with this namespace structure. How can it be that .Net finds it conflicting?

Comment: C# namespaces are crap. Java has the upper hand here. I'm forced to use C# sometimes and I always fully qualify namespaces when I have to refer to them. It just looks clearer in the code.

Comment: @Steve, could you elaborate? In what way are C# namespaces so much worse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to open a namespace in order to see it's types in C#. Types from sub-namesapces are not automatically visible. So, put the following on top of your code file:

```
using History.Antiquity.East;
```

Then you can directly access your type as follows:

```
Persia.Conquer();
```

By the way, your code samples look like a mixture of VB, C# and C++/CLI... what language are you actually using?

Comment: Accessing Persia that way is no problem. I'd rather however understand why I couldn't qualify a type in a descendent namespace, without having to include a using directive. You however explained why in the first paragraph. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean a mixture of code styles? I wrote that by hand in here. But I can't see how can that be confused with another language?

Comment: In your first piece of code, you write Namespace with a capital N, which is the VB way to write it. And while most of your second code piece is C#, "using namespace SomeThing.SomeThing;" is C++/CLI, not C#.

Comment: oh right! It's my c++ background calling and my lack of experience in C#. I should have written in an VS before and paste in here. I will edit the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While using partial namespaces like that is perfectly acceptable in VB, C# wasn't designed to work that way.

Comment: Wouldn't know about VB before you told me. But isn't this a common namespace implementation. C++ doesn't require of me to declare descendant namespaces either.

Answer (score 1):

The code gives you an error, because it should be just

```
using History.Antiquity;
```

But adding this in the code *doesn't* mean you can refer to the `History.Antiquity.East` namespace just by `East`.

What you can do is if you're in the `History` namespace, you can use `Antiquity.East`, but `using`s don't affect this.

Comment: Thanks. I now realize I need to "declare" the namespace through a using directive before I can use it. A somewhat annoying limitation if, as was the case, I would like to qualify my types in such a way as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace History
{
    using Antiquity;

    public class foo {
        public foo() {
            East.Persia.Conquer(); // error!
        }
    }
}
```

You could do something like this.